# retain the xml tags using query from eulexistdb

Tags: python, xquery, exist-db

I am using exist-db as a database for all my xml files and I used the eulexistdb python library to perform the queries. My question is, when i use the QuerySet command, it only returns the values from the xml data. Is there a way to retain the xml tags in the result? The reason is, it is easier for me to parse the result and it would be much cleaner as compared to parsing it using the index.

e.g

```
from eulexistdb import db
from eulexistdb.models import XmlModel
from eulexistdb.query import QuerySet

db = db.ExistDB(server_url=EXISTDB_SERVER_URL,username='user1',password='password1')
qs = QuerySet(using=db,model=XmlModel,xpath="//tag1")
```

the code above will only return the values and I was wondering if there is a way for it to return something like:

```
<tag1>
  <tag2>value2</tag2>
  <tag3>value3</tag3>
</tag1>
```

Please Help. Thank you.

Comment: You may find more users of eulexistdb on the eXist-open mailing list. You are welcome to join. https://sourceforge.net/projects/exist/lists/exist-open

Answer (score 1):

I am no Python expert, and I am not involved with eulexistdb, however you might take a look at their unit tests, which seem to show how to do the kinda thing you are asking - https://github.com/emory-libraries/eulexistdb/tree/master/test/test_existdb in particular `test_query.py` looks promising.

If not, perhaps contacting the Emory University team behind it via their GitHub or directly might help you.